# Use vscode insider extension API

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am writing a VSCode extension but I need to use the latest extension API. How do I tell my package.json to use the insider version of the vscode API in my extension? I've tried:

```
"devDependencies": {
    [...],
    "vscode": "^1.22.0-insider"
},
```

but I get:

```
$ npm install
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for vscode@^1.22.0-insider
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `package.json`, set:

```
"engines": {
    "vscode:" "*"
}
```

Then run the npm postinstall script again (or just run `npm install` to retrigger it)

`*` pulls in the latest `vscode.d.ts` from VS Code's actively developed branch on github. Make sure to change `engines` to a real VS Code version such as `"^1.28.0"` before shipping your extension